# How do I find and simplify $\frac{(g(t+h)-g(t))}h$ if $g(t) = 3t-5$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I start out with:
$\frac{(3(t+h)-5-3t-5)}2$

simplify to:

$\frac{(3t+3h-5-3t-5)}2$

then $\frac{(3h-10)}2$

I tried entering that end it wouldn't work. I've tried entering other forms of it and it is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Parentheses are your friend

Comment: You have `/h` in the title but `/2` in the body of the question. You have also lost some parentheses along the way.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h} & = \frac{(3(t+h)-5)-(3t-5)}{h} \\
& = \frac{3t+3h-5-3t+5}{h} \\
& = \frac{3h}{h}\\
& = 3 
\end{align}

I believe this is what you are after.

---

Just noticed the equation is in the form of First Principles Differentiation without the limit. Since $g(x)=3t-5$, $g'(x)=3$ which is a constant term.